# Titanium advices, global cloud object

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am starting to learn Titanium and appcelerator platform.
I want to create simple script which makes request to ACS.

As far as I understand, in Alloy framework I've to add cloud module in every controller (like index.js etc).

Can I add this to be available globally?
I've tried something like:

```
Alloy.Globals = {
    cloud: require('ti.cloud')
};
```

in alloy.js, but when I run:

```
Ti.API.info(cloud);
```

in my controller, I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cloud is not defined
```

How should I access my global variables? Should I define them some other way?

Comment: Mabye try `Ti.API.info(Alloy.Globals.cloud)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead requiring in every controller you could simply require the module in alloy.js (or app.js if you're not using alloy).

Just try this (in alloy.js):

```
Alloy.Globals.cloud = require('ti.cloud');
```

then in your controllers you can simply use:

```
var cloud =  Alloy.Globals.cloud;
```

And that's it.. use the cloud variable just the way you would use with require.